# Broken link "ask" on FAQ page

Tags: bug, status-completed

Broken link on FAQ page: https://english.stackexchange.com/ask is 404:

> Of course, if your question isn't adequately answered by these resources, feel free to **[ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/ask)** here on English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. Be sure to mention the research you've done and what you're still hoping to learn!

Comment: I don't see a reason for a downvote. The broken link is there (currently english.stackexchange.com/ask; should be english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

I've gone ahead and edited that page to fix the link.